Prove that $v_{p}(K^{\times}) = \frac{1}{e}\Bbb{Z}$, where $e \mid n = [K:\Bbb{Q}_{p}]$
I start learning about Algebraic Number Theory. To see the definition of $p$-adic valuation see this. I was trying to prove the result:

Prove that $v_{p}(K^{\times}) = \frac{1}{e}\Bbb{Z}$, where $e$ is a divisor of $n = [K:\Bbb{Q}_{p}]$ = degree of extension, and $K$ is a finite field extension of $\Bbb{Q}_{p}$.

My Attempt: First of all $v_{p}$ is a group homomorphism so, $v_{p}(K^{\times})$ is n additive subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}$. Now if we denote the norm by $N_{K/\Bbb F} : K \to \Bbb F$, so $N_{K/\Bbb F}(x) \in \Bbb Q_p$. We know that $v_p(x) \in \Bbb Z ~\forall~ x \in \Bbb Q_p$. Now as, $x \in K^{\times}$ then $v_p(x) = \frac{1}{n}v_p(N_{K/\Bbb Q_p}(x)) \in \frac{1}{n}\Bbb Z$, basically $\Bbb Z \subseteq v_p(K^\times) \subseteq \frac{1}{n}\Bbb Z$. Now note that $v_{p}(K^\times) = \{v_p(x) = \frac{f_x}{g_x} : x \in K^\times ~\&~ \gcd (f_x,g_x) = 1\}$. Now consider the set $E = \{g_x :\gcd (f_x,g_x) = 1 ~\text{where}~ v_p(x) = \frac{f_x}{g_x} \}$. This set is finite, because as $ v_p(K^\times) \subseteq \frac{1}{n}\Bbb Z$, so $g_x \mid n ~\forall~ x \in K^\times$, that is $g_x$ is the divisor of $n$. Let $e = \max E$ then $e \in E$. So there exists an $x \in K^\times$ such that $g_x = e$ and $v_p(x) = \frac{f_x}{e} = \frac{f}{e},$ where $f_x = f$. As $\gcd(f,e) = 1$ so, there exists $r,s \in \Bbb Z$ such that $rf + se = 1 \implies r\frac{f}{e} + s = \frac{1}{e}$. As $v_p(K^\times)$ is an additive subgroup so $\frac{f}{e} \in v_p(K^\times) \implies r\frac{f}{e} \in v_p(K^\times)$, also $s \in \Bbb Z \subseteq v_p(K^\times) \implies \frac{1}{e} \in v_p(K^\times) \implies \frac{1}{e}\Bbb Z \subseteq v_p(K^\times)$.
Now my question is: Can we claim that $v_p(K^\times) = \frac{1}{e} \Bbb Z$? I mean, as $e$ was chosen to be the largest possible denominator, I believe that $v_p(K^\times) = \frac{1}{e} \Bbb Z$. But the problem is, can we prove directly or if we assume there is $y \in v_p(K^\times)$ but $y \notin \frac{1}{e} \Bbb Z$, then we will have a contradiction?

This follows immediately from just $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq v_p(K^\times)\subseteq \frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z}$. (Scaling up, this is equivalent to finding a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ that contains $n\mathbb{Z}$.)

Thanks for the comment.  Are you saying that $n v_p(K^\times)$ is the subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ that contains $n \Bbb Z$? That looks like $f \Bbb Z$, where $f \mid n$. That is $n v_p(K^\times) = f \Bbb Z \iff v_p(K^\times) = \frac{1}{e} \Bbb Z$, where $e = n/f$

Yes, exactly that

This proves the result. But can we claim that $e$ will be the largest possible denominator, as I wrote in my proof?
